# How to loop in tbl_cross

Tags: loops

I have seven variables X1,...,X7
I need to crosstabulate all my variables: X1 with 6 others.
Is it possible to do it and how with tbl_cross?

```
AGR %>% 
  tbl_cross(
    row=X1,
    col =X2,
    percent = "row",
    digits = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Scott Hunter: R language. tbl_cross is function that creates a cross table of two categorical variables. see https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_cross.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'

tbl <-
  c("stage", "grade") %>%
  map(
    ~ trial %>%
      tbl_cross(row = all_of(.x), col = "trt", margin = "col") %>%
      bold_labels()
  ) %>%
  tbl_stack()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>